# How can I skip the 'Sign in with Google' button?

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-signin

I'd like users of my website to be able to sign in with their Google accounts and following the basic instructions [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in) I've been able to do so.

However, this relies on having a 'Sign in with Google' button somewhere for the user to click. How can I bypass this button so that the Google login window automatically pops open?

I have tried finding the `div` of the button and using `.click()` but this gets blocked by any browser's popup blocker.

Comment: We're working on a new UX for Google Sign-In, do you think this would be useful for your use case?It's an embedded one-tap account selection flow. Happy to give you access if you might be able to provide input / feedback. https://docs.google.com/document/d/1HvNJ8KlIO2tG_dqtU6o3WSUNrq6cFwFJsszc5BzX-eg

Comment: Would be interested if you have more details on the usage case / UX that you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Thank you @StevenSoneff but I feel like this may be a little bit above my current level of understanding :/

My website would also never be accessed from a mobile device - thank you though :)

Comment: @StevenSoneff I was hoping I could have the sign-in window pop open as soon as the page is loaded. This is because users must sign in with Google to use my website.